# How close to 2 does the value of x has to be so that x^2 is within 1/100th of 4

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

I came across this question in a book through which I am trying to learn Calculus. I understood the question clearly, however I want to know how to arrive at the answer solving through inequalities

**Scenario 1**

$ |x^2 - 4| < 0.01$

$-x^2 + 4 < 0.01 $

$-x^2 + 4 < 1/100 $

$- x^2 < (1/100) - 4$

$ x^2 > 4 - (1/100)$

$ x > \sqrt{399/100}$

**Scenario 2**

$x^2 - 4 < 0.01 $

$x^2 - 4 < 1/100 $

$x^2 < (1/100) + 4$

$ x < \sqrt{401/100}$

x has to be between $\sqrt{399/100}$ and $\sqrt{401/100}$ for the above equation to be within 1/100th to 4

Is my understanding correct?

Answer in the book is given as $\sqrt{401/100} - 2$ which I don't understand how

Comment: Take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342995/quadratic-absolute-value-inequality

Comment: Your Answer matches the text book Answer : (1) You have to subtract 2 from that range to get "how close to 2 it must be" , which is what the -2 is doing here. (2) More-over , the lower limit is weaker , while the upper limit is tighter , hence we take the over-all tighter limit.

Comment: Answer corresponds to question what is maximum $\delta$ such that $|x-2|\leq \delta \Rightarrow |x^2-4|\leq \frac{1}{100}$

Comment: @Prem What do you mean by weaker and tighter?

Comment: (A) I meant that $|\sqrt{3.99}-2|$ is larger (weaker) when compared to $|\sqrt{4.01}-2|$ which is smaller (tighter). (B) Example : It is tighter to state that $\pi$ is within 3.141 & 3.142 , rather than to state that $\pi$ is within 3 & 4 which is weaker.